# demodulate GFSK with quadrature demod

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Hi I am trying to demodulated a GFSK signal using gnu radio
I connected an osmocom source to FIR filter and the filter to Quadrature demod (which output the signal to a file)
as shown here:
[my flow graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DApr1.png)

the Quadrature demod gain is - samp_rate/(2*pi*deviation/8).

Using Audacity I opened the file containing the demodulated signal. however no matter what packet I send (even if I don't send anything) I don't see the peeks which suppose to stand for a packet.

[demodulated signal shown in audacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5o8g.png)

you can see hear an example ,it seems that my device is sending packets constantly.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change Sample Rate from 4M sps to a value greater than Ch0 Frequency (currently 868M Hz).

Comment: didn't work at all (result looks even worse)
in addition ,I was told that 4m sps is enough